# Flutter Localization for data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-localizations

I would like to localize my app in 4 different languages.

I have data that I retrieve from Firestore (i.e. titles, descriptions, etc)
What would be a good approach to do this? I found this library
https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization

What is the right approach? It seems easy to localize hardcoded strings but I can't find anything regarding dynamic data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `AssetLoader` to retrieve from Firestore, see for details [Easy Localization Loader](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization_loader). See [HttpAssetLoader](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization_loader/blob/master/lib/src/http_asset_loader.dart) for the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the approach found here [link](https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-to-implement-localization-in-flutter/) Do you reckon that i can change the string key value pairs for variables? `{
    “welcome_text”:“Hello, Welcome to my blog”,
    “first_text”:“This is App localization example”
}`  for example `description : description_EN and the other would be description : description_GR` So i can retrieve the variables with the translations with minor changes from the code i already have.